# Suppose $f(x+iy) = (x^2-y)+i(x-y^2)$. For which $z$ is $f$ continuous, differentiable, and analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have applied the Cauchy-Riemann-equations and don't think that this function is differentiable anywhere, but I'm just confused on how to rigorously show where it is continuous and differentiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$x=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}\quad \text{and}\quad y=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The function is continuous everywhere, since both its real and its imaginary parts are polynomial and therefore continuous.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations in this case are $2x=-2y$ and $1=1$. So, $f$ is differentiable at the points of the form $x-xi$ ($x\in\mathbb R$) and only at those points.

Finally, it is not analytic, since it is not differentiable outside the line $\operatorname{Im}z=-\operatorname{Re}z$.